# Angular How to prevent button click from opening window.open URL

Tags: angular, typescript, navigation

I have a button icon in a page which when clicked opens another application page in a new tab.

```
this.referenceAppPathProvider
                .Customer(item.customerNo)                
                .subscribe((refUrl) => {
                    window.open(refUrl, '_blank');
                });
```

This works fine.

I have a side navigation bar which contains a buttons.

```
<button bdsSidebarItem [routerLink]="['/trips']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" title="Shipments">
    <fa-icon bdsSidebarItemIcon [fixedWidth]="true" [icon]="iconTrips" class="duoIconTrips"></fa-icon>
    <span bdsSidebarItemText>Shipments</span>
</button>
```

The issue is, once I click and open the external app icon, whenever I click a menu item in the side nav, the correct app page opens but a new tab opens and the external app page is loaded once again. From then on, every click in the side nav, opens a new tab.

How do I prevent the previous URLs from being reopened again?

Comment: Would be useful to see more code - particularly the blocks that connect all the details you mentioned in the question.